# How to scroll to top of UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsrange

My code below scrolls all the way to the bottom of the text field. How can I do the reverse of this and have the code function to scroll to the very beginning of the text field?

```
let bottom = NSMakeRange(theTextView.text.characters.count - 1, 1)
theTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(bottom)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to set the `location` parameter of `NSMakeRange` to 0 instead of `theTextView.text.characters.count - 1`.

```
let bottom = NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)
```

A better way is to note that `UITextView` extends `UIScrollView`. So you can set the `contentOffset`:

```
theTextView.contentOffset = .zero
```

If your want to animate the scrolling, use:

```
theTextView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension :

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollToTop() {
        let desiredOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -contentInset.top)
        setContentOffset(desiredOffset, animated: true)
    }
}
```

usage :

```
textView.scrollToTop()
```